# dynamically redirect users to specific page based on where they came from

Tags: node.js

Let's say I have a route to `register` a user like:

```
router.post('/register', registerSchema, register);
```

Apparently inside the `register` function we save the new signed up user to database.

After registration, I want to **redirect** users to a specific page based on **where they come from**.

if user's come from `button 1` they should go to `dashboard` page.

if they come from `button 2` I want to redirect them to `payment` page ok?

How can I do this in a appropriate way?

I tried to send users to sign up page when they click on `button 1` to `href="signup?next=dashboard"`

But I cannot get the query string when they click on register button... clicking on register button don't care about where they came from it just hits the register route...

Comment: why don't you pass the information about where they came from in http headers data. if it's not GET request ofc and then redirect them according to the values you got.

Comment: what are you using in the front end ??!